# Python in windows opens a new console

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, subprocess, popen

I have some Python functions which execute batch commands with:

```
subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).stdout.read().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
```

Running this in Linux is ok, but running in Windows it opens a new console at every subprocess.Popen call and the previous console doesn't know about any modification made by the function in the new console.

How can I proceed?

Comment: It would help to know what you are using for `cmd`.  Also, I don't see that happening in Win7 with 2.7.2.  I don't see a window even when I use "pause" for `cmd`.  One last thing: You **cannot** affect the current _environment_ from a child _environment_.  That's not how it works (unless you do crazy stuff like setting the registry).  You _can_, however, affect the current environment before spawning the new one.  [See the documentation for os.environ](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ).

Answer (score -1):

your code are complex. i write python script for execute command:

```
import subprocess
import sys
subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,cmd],stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
```

if it's not work you can try this more easy:

```
import subprocess
import sys
proc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,cmd],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate()
```